# Using the <button> tag and jQuery in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple line of Javascript code

```
$('<button>').attr({ 'type': 'button' }).css({ 'cursor': 'pointer' }).text('Button').click(function  () { alert('clicked'); }).appendTo($('#btn'));
```

The html is even simpler

```
<div id='btn'>Click this button</>
```

Everything works when running this code FF as shown here on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kevinle/jJbNt/6/.  But it fails to run on IE8.

What would be the explanation (has this problem been documented somewhere that I miss) and what would the work-around be?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe close your `<div>` element properly?

```
<div id='btn'>Click this button</div>
```

#### EDIT

OK, tested it out more thoroughly, and found that the call to `.attr()` was dumbing down IE's Javascript engine. After removing that from your jQuery chain, it worked in IE8.

If you think about it, since you're instantiating a `<button>` anyway, you don't need to set it's `type` to `"button"`.

```
$('<button>')
    //.attr({ 'type': 'button' })
    .css({ 'cursor': 'pointer' })
    .text('Button')
    .click(function  () { 
        alert('clicked'); 
    })
    .appendTo('#btn')
    ;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9xUj5/

Comment: My careless mistake, but that wasn't it.  Still does not work after properly closing.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of problems:

1. Older versions of IE have some issues with the `<button>` tag which may or may not be your problem here.
2. There is no type attribute on the button tag.
3. You are missing a closing `</div>` in your HTML.
4. You should use `<input type="button">` instead.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/e8eGW/ for a working version.

```
<div id='btn'>Click this button</div>

$('<input type="button" value="Button">').css({ 'cursor': 'pointer' }).click(function  () { alert('clicked'); }).appendTo($('#btn'));
```

Comment: The <button> tag is supported in all versions of IE. IE6 has a bug in that it doesn't submit the value of the button, but other than that it's fully supported.

Comment: wait, I'm curious now; which versions don't support `button`? A quick search shows support all the way back to IE 4; is there something more obscure that you found?

Comment: There are various IE bugs associated with the button tag.  You can use it in many cases, but I find it safer to not worry about those bugs and use: `<input type="button" value="Button Text">` which also works fine in this case.

Comment: IE8 is old?  Hard sell to customers who just updated to IE8 from 6.  Missing closing div is just a mistake when I created the fiddle, i.e. after I see the problem in my code, I used jsfiddle to illustrate.  Unfortunately, a careless mistake.  3. is what I tried to achieve by using jQuery to construct the DOM.

Comment: IE8 is full of bugs.  It was released almost three years ago which is pretty darn old by the pace of web development and replaced by IE9 which has been out for 8 months.  Obviously one still has to support IE8, but yes it's old.  Who just upgraded from IE6 to IE8?  Why wouldn't one run IE9 if you're upgrading?  Standards support in IE9 is light years ahead of IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://jsfiddle.net/jJbNt/16/ - Shouldn't really make a difference, try it though.

Answer (score 0):

just take out the `.attr(...)` and it will work fine ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/7NpVc/1/)).

`button` doesn't seem to have a type attribute that is visible in IE from javascript; you were thinking maybe of `input`?

Comment: That's not true - `button` does have a type attribute - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

Comment: <button> does have a type attribute, with the possible options 'button', 'reset' and 'submit'.

Comment: Sorry, I was speaking in the context of IE and javascript; I've clarified (and many thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

It seems IE8 and older are having a problem parsing the 'type' attribute. Removing this or updating jQuery to 1.7 fixes solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for ie8

JQUERY:

```
$('button.buttonLink').click(function(){
  window.location = $(this).parent('a').attr('href');
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="logout.php"><button class="buttonLink">LOGOUT</button></a>
```